# babel-loader & babel-preset-es2015 not executing in webpack2 (chained with ts-loader)

Tags: typescript, babeljs, webpack-2

I've been struggling to get webpack2 to run babel-loader. basically with my current configuration babel does nothing and the result is passed to uglify which fails due to es2015 features remaining in my code.

If I look at the output file babel has done nothing, so I try running it via the CLI
`babel --preset es2015 catseye.bundle.js > catseye2.bundle.js`
this works fine the second file contains bableified code.

So something is up with my webpack config, but I cant for the life of me spot my error.

my versions should be up to date:

```
"babel-core": "^6.23.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
"ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
"webpack": "^2.2.1",
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "gl-matrix", path.join(__dirname, "src/catseye.ts")],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "catseye.bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader:"babel-loader",
            options:{
              presets:[
                ["es2015", {modules:false}]
              ]
            },
          },
         {
           loader: 'ts-loader'
         }
       ]

      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        dead_code: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ]
};
```